# Plot window division with viewports in R

Tags: r, viewport

I'm trying to achieve a simple division of the plot window with viewports, but something's not right.  The code below wants to achieve the first plot in the left hand 2/3rds of the window and the second in the right hand 1/3rd.  Grateful for an idea what I'm missing:

```
pushViewport(viewport())
pushViewport(viewport(x=0, y=0, width=.66, height=1, just=c("left","top")))
plot(rnorm(100))
popViewport(1)
pushViewport(viewport(x=.66, y=0, width=.33, height=1, just=c("left","top")))
plot(1:20, 1:20, add=T)
popViewport(2)
```

Alternatively I wonder if it's possible to replicate the following ggplot method with base plotting.  The code below is illustrative of method but does not work as is incomplete - but is [demo'd at rstudio-pubs-static](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trobt.png).  But is the method transferable?

```
a <- qplot(1:10, rnorm(10), main = "a")
b <- qplot(1:10, rnorm(10), main = "b")
c <- qplot(1:10, rnorm(10), main = "c")
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(2, 2)))
vplayout <- function(x, y) viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)
print(a, vp = vplayout(1, 1:2))  # key is to define vplayout
print(b, vp = vplayout(2, 1))
print(c, vp = vplayout(2, 2))
```

[image]

Comment: grid and base graphics are mostly incompatible (but see gridBase package if you really want to); in base graphics you'd use layout OR split.screen OR par(mfrow...)

Comment: BTW those are actually XOR  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use base graphics, then `layout` is an easy option:

```
layout(matrix(c(1, 2), 1, 2, byrow=TRUE), 
              widths=c(2/3, 1/3))
layout.show(n=2)
plot(rnorm(100))
plot(runif(100))
```

Comment: @geotheory [See also here](http://menugget.blogspot.com/2013/01/my-template-for-controlling-publication.html) for a particularly nice example of what can be accomplished with `layout()`.